# storyboardのpush segueでつないでいるのにmodalの動きをする

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard

storyboardで、
UIButtonからUINavigationControllerをrootViewに持つUITableViewController に
pushでsegueを繫いでいるのにもかかわらず、実行するとModalの動きをする。

ソースコードでは何も処理を行っていません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました。
結論としまして、
NavigationControllerからNavigationControllerにpushでつなぐとModalの動きをするようです。
遷移先のUITableViewはもともとTabControllerで別タブとして機能させていたため
storyboard上でrootViewがNavigationControllerになっておりました。

そして遷移元のViewControllerもNavigationControllerをrootViewに持つため
UINavigationController->TopViewController から、
UINavigationController->TableViewController へpush segueを繫いでおり
UINavigationController が二重になるような繋ぎ方になっていました。
この場合、エラーにはならず、Modalの動きになるようです。
遷移先のNavigationControllerを削除し、直接TableViewに繋ぎ直すことで修正できました。